# После обновления Babel появились warning'и. (without registering it in the scope tracker)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel

После обновление Babel. При компиляции приложения из TypeScript в JS, появляется большое количество варнингов, которые существенно тормозят сборку. Сама ошибка:

```
This problem is likely caused by another plugin injecting
*** without registering it in the scope tracker. If you are the author
of that plugin, please use "scope.registerDeclaration(declarationPath)".
The exported identifier "IBaseBooleanProps" is not declared in Babel's scope tracker
as a JavaScript value binding, and "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"
never encountered it as a TypeScript type declaration.
It will be treated as a JavaScript value.
```

За "***" название интерфейсов/типов которые экспортируются из файлов.

Пример экспорта типа на который ругается `Babel`:

```
export type InputType = 'text' | 'password' | 'number' | 'file' | 'submit'
```

Настройка `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env",
  "@babel/preset-typescript",
  [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    {
      "runtime": "automatic"
    }
  ]
],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]]
}
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Буду рад любой подсказке

Comment: тут вроде можно найти ответ на ваш вопрос https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10264